# Trying to make array element appear only once

Tags: java, android, arrays, random

So i'm trying to do this : when you click the image the text in the center changes to a random element from the array but i want every element that appears once to not appear again... I tried doing it like this but it didn't work please help me here!!

```
package com.example.bibiwars.skills;


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
            img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //ToastMessage to test the click ::::::
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            String[] Array = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
            int rnd = new Random().nextInt(Array.length);
            while (Array[rnd].equals("0"))
               {rnd = new Random().nextInt(Array.length);}
            text.setText(Array[rnd]);
            Array[rnd] = "0";
        }

    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



}
```

Comment: Move the closing brace from after the `rnd = ...;` line to after `Array[rnd] = "0";`. Voting to close as off-topic due to a typographical error.  By the way, simple debugging would have shown you the problem. Try to learn how to debug please.

Comment: I didn't even ask for that i'm asking how to make every element appears only once

Comment: I realize that. Your code would work as you want if you just move that brace.

Comment: okay, sorry I'm still a beginner but i'll do it next time thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save you array as field variable, and actually remove an entry once chosen. This way you don't get the same twice.

```
package com.example.bibiwars.skills;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
final ArrayList<String> places =  = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"));

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //ToastMessage to test the click ::::::
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            if(places.size() >0)
            {
                int rnd = new Random().nextInt(places.size());
                text.setText(places.get(rnd));
                places.remove(rnd);
            }
        }

    });
}
//... other methods...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

shuffle array

```
// Implementing Fisher–Yates shuffle
  static void shuffleArray(int[] ar)
  {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
      // Simple swap
      int a = ar[index];
      ar[index] = ar[i];
      ar[i] = a;
    }
  }
```

And when you click show next array element.

Comment: this is one that i liked and really thought to make in the beginning but i wanted to delete an element after using it... anyway thank you